# Performing a shift with a group by

Tags: python, group-by, shift

I am working on a task where I want to shift all values in the column but only shift the values that are mapped to their opty_number, so that it doesn't completely mess up my data frame. I have attempted the following code below can anyone help me with documentation or packages.

```
Data.groupby('OPTY_NUMBER', group_keys=False).transform(TRANSITION_BY = Data.TRANSITION_BY.shift(-1))
```

Comment: What is `Data`? Which library do you use?

Comment: Data is my data frame. The problem I am facing is that I want to shift values in the transition_by column up 1. The following code will shift all values up Data.TRANSITION_BY = Data.TRANSITION_BY.shift(-1) -- But I want to do the shift on a group by so i have a proper matching to their ID.

Comment: You aren't answering my question. What is the **type** of `Data`? A class?